# Feed content type field with configuration value

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have a config form with several config variables where i save some user preferences like «position» or «weight»

Now, at the moment of generating a content type i want to feed a select field with the «position» config formerly mentioned saved values as options for this field.

I saw i would may create a reference field as a view reference. So i guess i would do before a view printing those values, but i guess if there is a more convenient way to do this.

I prefer to do it without code, using the gui.

PS: I'm doing this with a simple config form, for customer's reasons i can not use Configuration Entity Types :-/

Answer (score 0):

finally, I decided to do a custom autocomplete for the field with a validation in the form submission :-S